# blue/green deployment method for a service that contains Kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, project-reactor

we are using the blue/green deployment method for a service that contains Kafka consumers. The issue that we are facing is that both the blue and green pods are consuming from the same topic, preventing us from having isolated soft-launch and regular environments. Is there an advised programatic approach to handle this scenario?